# Redux-saga - yield all is not calling all my sagas in root saga

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I've a two sagas to be called onto the same page.But then only one saga results are seen. 
The other saga is not executing I don't see the  results.

AdminFolder

dashboard.js

```
               const mapStateToProps=state=>{
                console.log(state)
                return{   
                    dataSales:state.salesDataReducer,
                    mostBrought:state.mostBroughtReducer
                }
                };

                const mapDispatchToProps = {
                    getSales:getSales,
                    getMostBrought:getMostBrought
                };
```

rootSaga/rootSaga.js

```
                import actionWatcherSalesData from '../adminDashboard/salesDataSaga';
                import actionWatcherMostBrought from '../adminDashboard/mostBroughtSaga';
                import {all,call} from 'redux-saga/effects';



                export default function *rootSaga(){
                    yield all([
                    call( actionWatcherSalesData), //works
                    call(actionWatcherMostBrought)// this saga doesn't call up no data found 
                    ]);
                }

                    export default function *rootSaga(){
                    yield all([
                    fork( actionWatcherSalesData),
                    fork(actionWatcherMostBrought)//doesnt work
                    ]);
                }
```

saga1.js

```
 yield takeLatest(GET_SALES_DATA,getSales)
```

saga2.js

```
 yield takeLatest(GET_MOST_BROUGHT_DATA,getMostBrought);
```

Is it takeLatest which is causing the issue?

1)As its the same page data both the call must happen async but the second saga call is not called ?
2)I have a doubt that for my application on other page I've a button only on click it must call the saga should that be include here?

In this call,fork,all is not working. PLease lemme know this where I'm going wrong.have I missed onto to something?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My bad the imports were wrong

The following works like a charm :)

```
  export default function *rootSaga(){
   yield fork(actionWatcherSalesData)
   yield fork(actionWatcherMostBrought)
   }
```